# Determine Image URL From Data URI

Tags: css, data-uri

Is it possible to find the absolute url of an image embedded in a page with a data URI tag? Inspecting the html element in Chrome renders the image (pictured below), but 'Opening the image in a new Tab' renders the following html:

```
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="48px" height="48px" viewBox="0 0 48 48" enable-background="new 0 0 48 48" xml:space="preserve">
    <path id="user-icon" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M41.645,36.131c-6.877-1.586-13.278-2.977-10.18-8.82C40.902,9.516,33.967,0,24,0 C13.837,0,7.07,9.881,16.535,27.311c3.193,5.881-3.45,7.27-10.18,8.82c-6.875,1.586-6.347,5.211-6.347,11.787H47.99 C47.99,41.342,48.52,37.717,41.645,36.131z"/>
</svg>
```

Insepcting the element in Chrome yields:
[image: Screen shot of image info in Chrome debugger]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no URL - the data contains the actual content of the image, similar to what you would see if you opened the image in a text editor (though encoded differently). There is no image file on the server.